# Prove the uniqueness of a solution to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE in question is

$$y'(t)= -y(t) -\cos(t) + 5.$$

We also know that $y(0)=0$.

All we did in this mathcourse is separation of variables, meaning we cant use something like the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem

I already tried this approach but it seems to fail:
Let $u$ and $v$ be solutions, then:

$$u'+u= -\cos(t) + 5 =v'+v$$
Meaning:
$$ u'-v' + u-v = 0.$$
This seems to be the dead end for me.
We also know that the solution to a linear ODE $y'(t) = F(y(t))h(t)$ with $y(t_0)=a$ where $t_0$ and $a$ are variables has a unique solution.
But the ODE in question isn't in this form and rewrtiting it doesnt help.
Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $w:=u-v$, then $w$ satisfies the ODE :$$w'+w=0$$ whose solution is $w(t) =ce^{-t} $, bu $0=w(0)=c$,So $w=0$ identically, meaning that $u=v$, i.e the Solution is unique.